# Problem with MediaComposition video rendering

Tags: c#, uwp

I am trying to generate an MP4 video from a simple MediaComposition, but the generated file is not recognized by any video player application. This is my test code, what could be wrong? Any help is most welcome. Thanks.

```
private async void nviSave_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MediaComposition mediaComposition;
        var random = new Random();

        var clip1 = MediaClip.CreateFromColor(Colors.AliceBlue, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(90));
        mediaComposition.Clips.Add(clip1);

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            var clip2 = MediaClip.CreateFromColor(Color.FromArgb(Convert.ToByte(random.Next(0, 255)),
                Convert.ToByte(random.Next(0, 255)),
                Convert.ToByte(random.Next(0, 255)),
                Convert.ToByte(random.Next(0, 255))),
                TimeSpan.FromSeconds(90));

            mediaOverlayLayer = AddOverlay(mediaComposition, clip2, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0), 100, 300, 40 + (3 * i), 40, 1);
        }

        mediaComposition.OverlayLayers.Add(mediaOverlayLayer);

        var picker = new Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileSavePicker();
        picker.SuggestedStartLocation = Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerLocationId.VideosLibrary;
        picker.FileTypeChoices.Add("MP4 files", new List<string>() { ".mp4" });
        picker.SuggestedFileName = "RenderedComposition.mp4";

        Windows.Storage.StorageFile file = await picker.PickSaveFileAsync();
        if (file != null)
        {
            // Call RenderToFileAsync
            await mediaComposition.RenderToFileAsync(file);

        }
    }

private MediaOverlayLayer AddOverlay(MediaComposition mediaComposition, MediaClip overlayMediaClip, TimeSpan delay, double width, double height, double left, double top, double opacity)
    {
        Rect overlayPosition;

        overlayPosition.Width = width;
        overlayPosition.Height = height;
        overlayPosition.X = left;
        overlayPosition.Y = top;

        MediaOverlay mediaOverlay = new MediaOverlay(overlayMediaClip);
        mediaOverlay.Position = overlayPosition;
        mediaOverlay.Opacity = opacity;
        mediaOverlay.Delay = delay;
        mediaOverlayLayer.Overlays.Add(mediaOverlay);
        return mediaOverlayLayer;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am trying to generate an MP4 video from a simple MediaComposition, but the generated file is not recognized by any video player application.

I tried your code, it looks correct, but you forgot to display the rendering progress, and if the rendering is not complete, the video file will not be recognized. so please add the following code, and play the video after trimmed clip saved

```
var saveOperation = mediaComposition.RenderToFileAsync(file, MediaTrimmingPreference.Precise);

saveOperation.Progress = new AsyncOperationProgressHandler<TranscodeFailureReason, double>(async (info, progress) =>
{
    await this.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, new DispatchedHandler(() =>
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Saving file... Progress: {0:F0}%", progress));
    }));
});
saveOperation.Completed = new AsyncOperationWithProgressCompletedHandler<TranscodeFailureReason, double>(async (info, status) =>
{
    await this.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, new DispatchedHandler(() =>
    {
        try
        {
            var results = info.GetResults();
            if (results != TranscodeFailureReason.None || status != AsyncStatus.Completed)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Saving was unsuccessful");
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Trimmed clip saved to file");
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            // Update UI whether the operation succeeded or not
        }

    }));
});
```

And here is official [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/media-compositions-and-editing#render-the-composition-to-a-video-file) that you could refer to.

Comment: Even with this change the problem persists. The generated file is not recognized by any video player application.x

Comment: That's strange, it could render  recognized  video  in my side, Could you tell the video size?

Comment: This is a strange thing. Each time I generate the file, it has a different size: 2022Kb, 2947Kb, 9670Kb,...

Comment: It's not complete video file, it is 30m video file in my side. please check vs debug output , and check if the progress is 100%

Comment: You are right. I was canceling the process before the end. It takes an incredible twenty minutes to render the video. And when I try to increase the number of overlays, it crashes because of insufficient memory. Any suggestions to work around this issue?